# Stack Exchange Java client library

Tags: library, java, obsolete

### Sample Code

```
/**
 * The following will print out the current stats for the
 * Stack Overflow site (stackoverflow.com).
 */
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stats stats = StackAppClient.getStats();
        System.err.println(stats);
    }
}
```

### About

A Java client library that wraps the Stack Apps API. The library uses the newer [Jersey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services#Jersey) [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) processing that will eventually become part of the Java platform.

#### Change Log

Version 0.9

- Added support for the version 0.9 of the API

#### License

MIT

#### Download

Clone it from [the GitHub repository](http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/Stack-Apps-Java-Library).

#### Platform

Anywhere that Java can run.

### Contact

Send me a message on GitHub or use [my site contact form](http://www.ioncannon.net/contact/).

### Code

You can find [all the code on GitHub](http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/Stack-Apps-Java-Library), feel free to fork it.

Comment: Any idea about MVN Hosting..??

is it available as an artifact

Comment: Also where can i raise bugs on this..??

Comment: @VineetVerma, I suspect this project is long dead and raising bugs will do no good.  Nevertheless, you can do it at GitHub.  But you're probably better pursuing a library that works on API V2 or later.

Comment: I guess so...nothing works in this lib anymore..