# Answers information with tags

Tags: feature-request

I am trying to chart the up votes on answers received by a user by tags. Something like:

[image: upvotes]

I am running into the same situation as this question: [How to filter getAnswersForUser by tag?](https://stackapps.com/questions/575/how-to-filter-getanswersforuser-by-tag).

If the answers APIs return the tags with the answers themselves then that will save a huge number of calls.

Can this feature be added?

Answer (score 1):

I agree a lot of these "convenience" methods need to be added to the API, for the benefit of the bandwidth, programmers and users.