# SOCharts: Charts by Tags

Tags: app, tags, java

### Screenshot

I created this small app as a weekend hack. It shows the reputations, upvotes, downvotes and accepted answers for a user against the tags for the answers.

[image: Upvotes]

### About

I wanted to know how many upvotes I was away from getting the bronze badge for the [clojure] tag. But I could not find any straightforward way of doing that. So I wrote this app (in Clojure, of course).

The SO API is used for the data and the charts are created using the Google Chart API. The charts are opened in the default browser.

#### License

Licensed under EPL 1.0.

#### Download

If you have Clojure and Leiningen installed, you can simply get the code from https://gist.github.com/725331, save it as `socharts.clj` and then run

```
lein repl -e "(load \"socharts\")(refer 'socharts.socharts)(-main)"
```

for launching the Swing UI

[image: UI]

If you don't have Clojure installed, but have Java then download the standalone jar from http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5247/socharts-1.0.0-standalone.jar and run it as

```
javaw -jar socharts-1.0.0-standalone.jar
```

Once the UI is launched, just type your user id in the input box and press <ENTER>. It will take some time to download the data from the SO API (the progress bar shows the download progress) and then it will open the charts in your default browser.

You can also run it as a command line app by running

```
lein repl -e "(load \"socharts\")(refer 'socharts.socharts)(-main <userid>)"
```

or

```
java -jar socharts-1.0.0-standalone.jar <userid>
```

where you replace `<userid>` with your user id.

Be warned that because of a [missing feature](https://stackapps.com/questions/1822/answers-information-with-tags) in the SO API, it will fetch the data for each question you have answered. So the maximum limit is 10000 answers (the SO API call limit).

#### Platform

All platforms with Java 1.6.

### Contact

You can reach me at abhinav [at] abhinavsarkar [dot] net. Please report bugs/comments/suggestions as answers to this post.

### Code

The code was written in Clojure with the UI in Swing. It is available at https://gist.github.com/725331. It's a public gist so you can fork it if you like to do some changes.

Comment: +1 sweet I've tried it on OSX, you might want to change the title of this question with "socharts: chart tags statistics" for example or whatever you want.

Comment: +1 for the first Clojure app around - quite interesting :) I have encountered API throttling bans twice during testing with the jar version, so you might look into this eventually - see [Request Throttling Limits](http://stackapps.com/questions/1143/) for the background and [API compliant request throttle implementations](http://stackapps.com/questions/1322/) for some examples.

Comment: I just want to echo what @Steffen said: it really burns through API requests and locked me out for a few minutes.

Comment: @George @Steffen Didn't know about the API throttling bans. I'll make changes to avoid it.

Comment: I have made changes to respect API throttling limits. I think the app should work fine now.

Comment: @abhin4v - thanks, works without throttle problems now!