# How can I use the Stack Exchange API to get the total score on answers to questions with a specific tag?

Tags: support, api, tags, answers

I want to use the API to get the sum of all scores of my answers to questions having a specific tag.

I started using [top-user-answers-in-tags](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-answers-in-tags) method, but it only returns the top 30, whereas I want them all.

Comment: Do you want **upvotes** (as stated in the title) ***or* score** (as stated in the body?  [They are not the same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/52792/148310).  The answer, below, uses score -- since that's what drives badges, privileges, etc. -- but it could easily switch to upvotes, ***except***, that it's not always possible to tell which upvotes are *Community Wiki* (IE, don't count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to use [the `/users/{ids}/answers` path](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) to download all of a user's answers, and then filter out the tags and/or tot-up the scores from there.

Pseudo code:

```
scoreByTag = [] // Empty associative array

while (more pages of results) {
    1) Fetch next page of answers

    2) Store results and/or update scoreByTag array
}

Display/use select tag score(s) as desired.
```

Note that [there is already a page that does this](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/7).  It displays a user's tag scores for all his tags, with handy searching and sorting:

[image: Score by tags page]

[**Here's the results for your Stack Overflow account.**](http://jsbin.com/azeqec/7?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=270348)

See, also [How to filter getAnswersForUser by tag?](https://stackapps.com/questions/575/how-to-filter-getanswersforuser-by-tag), for a similar solution on the old API.

Comment: Thanks - this is perfect.  I didn't realize you could use filters to get the tags in the response of the answers API.